# How to chain multiple $.done's to run functions in a certain order

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-events

I'm trying to run the following code in the exact order that it is written, with nothing skipping it's previous function.  Is there a way to do this?  I know making use of jQuery's `$.done()` would be useful here, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed, so help would be appreciate.  Here's the code:

```
function roundOne () {          
    setTimeout(function () { 
        terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ 'found.');
        j++;                     
        if (j < numberOfRowsToFind) {            
            roundOne();            
        }                        
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
}
roundOne(); 

j = 0;
function roundTwo () {          
    setTimeout(function () { 
        terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ ' found.');
        j++;                     
        if (j < numberOfRowsToFind) {            
            roundTwo();            
        }                        
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
}
roundTwo();

j = 0;
function roundThree () {          
    setTimeout(function () { 
        terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ ' found.');
            j++;                     
            if (j < currentSrgValues[0][1]) {            
                roundThree();            
            }                        
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
}
roundThree();          
          
laddaCalculateButton.stop();
```

Comment: Do you really mean for each function to call `roundOne()` from inside it?  If so, how do you know when you're really done?  Also, can you structure your functions not to share a global variable (how about passing them an argument?).  That really complicates any use of chained promises to solve this issue.

Comment: The intended flow here is not clear.  `roundOne()` calls itself a certain number of times.  Then, you want `roundTwo()` to run, but when it runs it calls `roundOne()` a certain number of times which will then call itself a certain number of times.  Then, when all that is done, you want `roundThree()` to run which will again call `roundOne()` which will again call itself a bunch of times?  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Excuse me, that's a silly error in my code.  Each function should only be recursively calling itself, let me edit that.

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense.  I've now put a solution that uses promises in my answer below.  It also appears that you may have this `if (j < numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne)` wrong in `roundTwo()` since it's identical to `roundOne()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all the functions above making them run the next function inside of the previous one. Then you'll call `roundOne()` and you'll be done.

```
function roundOne () {          
    setTimeout(function () { 
        terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ 'found.');
        j++;                     
        if (j < numberOfRowsToFind) {            
            roundOne();            
        }  else {
            j = 0; // finished, set j=0 and call roundTwo  
            roundTwo();  
        }               
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
}

function roundTwo () {          
    setTimeout(function () { 
        terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ ' found.');
        j++;                     
        if (j < numberOfRowsToFind) {            
            roundTwo();            
        } else {
            j = 0; // finished, set j=0 and call roundThree
            roundThree();     
        }                   
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
}

function roundThree () {          
    setTimeout(function () { 
        terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ ' found.');
            j++;                     
            if (j < currentSrgValues[0][1]) {            
                roundThree();            
            } else {
                laddaCalculateButton.stop(); // finished all the three rounds        
            }            
    }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
}

j = 0;
roundOne();
```

Comment: I corrected your logic errors like calling roundOne inside roundTwo and Three etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately it still seems to run asynchronously..perhaps I'm doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use promises and get rid of the global variable, you could do it like this.  There's no real need to use promises here because you could just have `roundOne` call `roundTwo` when it's done and so on, but using promises is a bit more general purpose since you can then reuse these in any order by using promises.

```
function roundOne () {       
    var def = $.Deferred();   
    var j = 0;

    function run() {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ 'found.');
            j++;                     
            if (j < numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne) {            
                run();            
            } else {
               // done with roundOne()
               def.resolve();
            }
        }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
    }
    run();
    return def.promise();
}

function roundTwo () {          
    var def = $.Deferred();   
    var j = 0;

    function run() {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ ' found.');
            j++;                     
            if (j < numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne) {            
                run();            
            } else {
                // done with roundTwo
                def.resolve();
            }                       
        }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
    }
    run();
    return def.promise();
}

function roundThree () {          
    var def = $.Deferred();   
    var j = 0;

    function run() {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            terminal.echo('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row ' +(j+1)+ ' found.');
                j++;                     
                if (j < currentSrgValues[0][1]) {            
                    run();            
                } else {
                    // done with roundThree
                    def.resolve();
                }
        }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
    }
    run();
    return def.promise();
}

// then you sequence them like this
roundOne().then(roundTwo).then(roundThree);
```

---

And, if these functions are really as much the same as they seem, you could probably really [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) them up a lot like this by passing in the msg and the limit to a common block of code:

```
function runRound(msg, limit) {
    var def = $.Deferred();   
    var j = 0;

    function run() {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            terminal.echo(msg.replace("%d", j+1));
            j++;                     
            if (j < limit) {            
                run();            
            } else {
               // done with round
               def.resolve();
            }
        }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
    }
    run();
    return def.promise();    
}

runRound('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row %d found.', numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne)
    .then(function() {
       return runRound('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row %d found.', numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne);
    }).then(function() {
       return runRound('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row %d found.', currentSrgValues[0][1]);
    });
```

---

And, here's a DRY version that doesn't use promises:

```
function runRounds(msg, limits) {
    var j = 0;
    var limit = limits.shift();

    function run() {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            terminal.echo(msg.replace("%d", j+1));
            j++;                     
            if (j < limit) {            
                run();            
            } else {
                // done with round - if more to go, run again
                if (limits.length) {
                    runRounds(limits);
                }

            }
        }, Math.floor((Math.random() * (1500)) + (70 * j)))
    }
    run();
}

runRounds('Lambda and mu row checks passed.  Row %d found.', [numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne, numberOfRowsToFindInRoundOne, currentSrgValues[0][1]]);
```